# Computer freezes when running intel HD drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I removed my GPU (gtx 980) and when I use the Intel HD 4600 grapchis, my computer freezes every time about 10 seconds after boot.
I tried:

- Increasing core voltage
- Reinstalling drivers
- Reinstalling Ubuntu
- Set the memory for integrated gpu in the bios to 512MB
- Setting bios defaults

It even hangs in the OS installation screen. Everything freezes and I can't do anything.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome, i4790k (not overclocked)

Is this a problem with Ubuntu or my CPU?